# Issue with multiple routes in one file - only two out of three work, the last one won't work

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm working on making an API using express and MySQL. I'm having issues with my routes. I have it in a separate folder, requiring the different controller files and exporting the router at the end. Here's the issue. The last router.get function will not work. I can swap it and whatever is last will not work. I'll get back an empty array. I'm at a loss as to what can be wrong. Here's my code, the routes file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const getEmployeesController = require('../controllers/getEmployees');
const getEmployeesByIdController = require('../controllers/getEmployeesById');
const getEmployeesByFirstNameController = require('../controllers/getEmployeesByFirstName');



router.get('/', getEmployeesController.getEmployees);

router.get('/:id', getEmployeesByIdController.getEmployeesById);

router.get('/:first_name', getEmployeesByFirstNameController.getEmployeesByFirstName);


module.exports = router;
```

The 'first_name' router worked when it was second, after the '/', but now it won't. Same with the 'id', worked when its second, but not when it's third.

Here's the controller function, one as an example:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const pool = require('../mysql/connection')
const { handleSQLError } = require('../mysql/error')

const getEmployeesById = (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?"
  sql = mysql.format(sql, ['*', 'employees', 'emp_no', req.params.id])

  pool.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) return handleSQLError(res, err)
    return res.json(rows);
  })
}

  module.exports = { getEmployeesById };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/:first_name` and `/:id` match the exact same URLs so only the first one you register is going to get all the matching URLs.  They both match `/anything`.

You really can't define routes like that.  There's no way Express knows which route handler you want to use with `/anything` is the requested URL.

Instead, you need to define a route structure where those two types of URLs are different and you can design a route handler that will uniquely catch each one.  I personally don't ever use top level wildcard routes like this because they match every top level URL and they prohibit you using top level URLs for any other purpose in your site.

Instead, you might change your URL design to do this:

```
router.get('/id/:id', ...)
router.get('/firstname/:firstname', ...);
```

Then, it would be completely clear from the URL what type of resource was being requested and each route would match only the appropriate URLs.

Comment: @hbrashid - When a url comes in looking like `/something`, how is Express supposed to know if that's an id or a name?  It can't.  You've specified two top level wildcard routes that both match any top level URL.  They don't match unique things.  Let's say you send `/john` as the URL.  Express first evaluates the `/:id` route and says, hey `/john` matches that and it calls that route handler.